# Convert Integer in DBF IV to text with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, dbf

I've tried to research this problem online and need clarification.  I would say that I'm still a novice when it comes to programming with Access VBA, so any help would be great!

Currently have an Access database that records individual's comments and recommendations on potential changes to some spatial data.  I extract the .dbf of the ESRI shapefile and rename and save it to another location.  I've found code reads the .dbf columns and creates a temporary Access table that I then extract only the fields I need based on the type of data imported to other tables. It was working perfectly until we received a shapefile that contained integers and Access tries to convert those columns to Double.

Is there a way that I can convert the integers in the .dbf to text/Double in code to avoid this problem? The dbfs are not static in nature and maybe contain additional columns, etc. so I need a solution where it can be dynamic.

What I've read is that the dbf do not support the Alter Table commands and the only other solution I've found is to import into Excel and either import into Access that way or potentially write it back to a different .dbf.

I'm hoping that there might be an easier solution as the users will be the ones importing the .dbfs and are likely going to become frustrated.

I've set up a msgbox to display the column headers and the file type. In cases where the code changed the header from integer to double, I get Error Number 3292 = Syntax Error in field definition

```
Function ImportDBF(ByVal dbfFileDir As String, _
                    ByVal dbfTableName As String)

    dbfFileDir = dbfFileDir & "\\"

    Dim dbfCn As Object
    Dim dbfRs As Object
    Dim dbfStrSql As String
    Dim dbfStrConnection As String

    Set dbfCn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    dbfStrConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & dbfFileDir & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=dBase IV"

    dbfStrSql = "SELECT * FROM " & dbfTableName & ""

    dbfCn.Open dbfStrConnection

    Set dbfRs = dbfCn.Execute(dbfStrSql)

    Dim fieldIndex As Integer
    Dim ddlNewAccessTable As String
    Dim ddlColumns As String
    Dim dmlInsert As String
    Dim dmlColumns As String
    Dim dmlValues As String
    Dim CValue As String

    dmlColumns = "("
    ddlColumns = "("

    For fieldIndex = 0 To dbfRs.Fields.Count - 1

        dmlColumns = dmlColumns & dbfRs.Fields(fieldIndex).Name & ","

       ' MsgBox dbfRs.Fields(fieldIndex).Name, vbOKOnly

        Select Case dbfRs.Fields(fieldIndex).Type
            Case 202
               ddlColumns = ddlColumns & dbfRs.Fields(fieldIndex).Name & " " & _
                            "TEXT,"
            Case 203
                ddlColumns = ddlColumns & dbfRs.Fields(fieldIndex).Name & " " & _
                            "MEMO,"
            Case 7
                ddlColumns = ddlColumns & dbfRs.Fields(fieldIndex).Name & " " & _
                            "DATETIME,"
            Case 11
                ddlColumns = ddlColumns & dbfRs.Fields(fieldIndex).Name & " " & _
                            "YESNO,"
            Case 2
                ddlColumns = ddlColumns & dbfRs.Fields(fieldIndex).Name & " " & _
                            "INTEGER,"
            Case 3
                ddlColumns = ddlColumns & dbfRs.Fields(fieldIndex).Name & " " & _
                            "LONG,"
            Case 131
                ddlColumns = ddlColumns & dbfRs.Fields(fieldIndex).Name & " " & _
                            "DECIMAL,"
            Case 5
                ddlColumns = ddlColumns & dbfRs.Fields(fieldIndex).Name & " " & _
                            "DOUBLE,"
            Case Else
                ddlColumns = ddlColumns & dbfRs.Fields(fieldIndex).Name & " " & _
                            "TEXT,"
        End Select

    Next fieldIndex

    dmlColumns = Left(dmlColumns, Len(dmlColumns) - 1) & ")"

    ddlColumns = Left(ddlColumns, Len(ddlColumns) - 1) & ")"

    ddlNewAccessTable = "CREATE TABLE " & "Test" & " " & ddlColumns & ";"

    MsgBox ddlColumns

    Dim myDb As Database
    Set myDb = CurrentDb()
    myDb.Execute ddlNewAccessTable  **This is where the code fails
```

I'm hoping that someone will be able to point me in the right direction.  I would like a backend solution that doesn't involve a lot of user interaction and ideally without going through Excel.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the DDL SQL that you actually try to Execute in the last line?

Comment: Hi Kismet.  The code appears to fail when I try to create the using the columns.    Dim myDb As Database
    Set myDb = CurrentDb()
    myDb.Execute ddlNewAccessTable  **This is where the code fails ddlNewAccessTable = "CREATE TABLE " & "Test" & " " & ddlColumns & ";" - SQL statement   ddlNewAccessTable = "CREATE TABLE " & "Test" & " " & ddlColumns & ";"

Comment: myDB. Execute  ddlNewAccessTable = Create Table Test (Area Double, Perimeter Double, SUB008_shr Double, SUB008_S_1 Double, AWS_YR Double, BlockID Text, SILVSYS Text,  Block Double (it was Long Int,), Note Text)

Comment: In Access, I chose Create, Query Design from the toolbar. I picked SQL view, pasted your SQL in, and tried to execute the query. The problem is with the `Note` column name. `Note` is a reserved word in Access SQL. When I changed it to `MyNote`, the query ran fine, and made a Test table.